Is there a standard Java method to read/write to the tty when stdout / stderr are redirected?
Many Unix programs such as mysql and expect are able to send messages directly to the user's tty, bypassing redirected stdout and stderr streams. For example, mysql is able to print a password prompt, and expect has send_tty.
Is there a built-in way to do this in Java, or is my only option to manually open /dev/tty and write to it?
I tried to use System.console() methods, but the console() is null when standard streams are redirected.
This is what I am using currently, which is not terrible but certainly more complex than System.out.println().
try {
  FileWriter tty = new FileWriter("/dev/tty", true);
  tty.write("This will always appear in the tty.\n");
  tty.flush();
  tty.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}


I wish System.console() actually worked, but it does not. :(
